# How to change text in other line when the pattern is found?

Tags: substitute, replace, multiple-lines

I've got this 4-line content:

```
foo
baa
baz
quz
```

and I'd like to replace `baa` to `bar` only when `quz` is found.

I've tried these commands (which highlights `baa` correctly, but says it's not found):

```
:/quz/s/baa/bar/
:/quz/1,$s@baa@bar@
```

> E486: Pattern not found: baa

and this:

```
:/quz/%s/baa/bar/
:/baa/,/quz/%s/baa/bar/
```

> E488: Trailing characters

and this:

```
/quz/s/baa/bar/
/quz/%s/baa/bar/
```

> search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP

What I am doing wrong? What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Are you sure that every line having quz will have its predecessor line having baa?

Comment: Yes, let assume 'baa' is always before 'quz'.

Comment: By before, I mean not only in the previous line (one line up), but it could be two lines before as well or in any other line before.

Comment: OK. I will delete my answer then and write it when I come up with good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:/baa/,/quz/s/baa/bar/` works, but that will only work with the first occurrence of `baa`.  If you want to replace all occurrences of `baa` with `bar` that come before `quz`:

```
,/quz/s/baa/bar
```

If your scenario calls for replacing all occurrences of `baa` if `quz` is found:

```
 /quz/,%s/baa/bar
```

That will replace all occurrences of `baa` with `bar` if `quz` is found.  This is basically using the range `/quz/,1,$` which is permitted  (`%` is equivalent to `1,$`).

From `:h cmdline-ranges`

> If more line specifiers are given than required for the command, the first one(s) will be ignored.

So if the first line specifier `/quz/` fails, it generates an error and causes the rest of the command to not execute.  But, if it does find a match, the `1,$` range is used since substitution only needs 2 range specifiers.

#### Conditional substitution

If you want to conditionally replace `baa` with `bar`, you'll want to use the `:global` command.

---

If you want replace `baa` with `bar` if it comes *before* `quz`:

```
:g/quz/?baa?,s//bar
```

Explanation:

```
g/quz/   - Moves to the next 'quz'
?baa?,   - Create a range from the last 'baa' to the current line
s//bar   - Reuse the previous pattern (baa) and substitute with 'bar'
```

However, that only matches the first `baa` that comes before `quz`.

---

If you want to replace all occurrences of `baa` that comes *before* `quz`:

```
g/quz/?quz\|\%^?,s/baa/bar
```

Explanation:

```
g/quz/       - Moves to the next 'quz'
?quz\|\%^?,  - Create a range from the previous 'quz' or the
               beginning of the buffer.
s/baa/bar    - Replace 'baa' with 'bar'
```

---

If you want to replace all occurrences of `baa` with `bar` if they're *between* two `quz` lines:

```
g/quz/silent! ??,s/baa/bar
```

Explanation:

```
g/quz/      - Moves to the next 'quz'
silent!     - The first occurence of 'quz' won't have a previous
              'quz' match. So, ignore the error about an invalid
              range.
??,         - Reuse 'quz' pattern to search for the previous occurrence
s/baa/bar   - Replace 'baa' with 'bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it was very close and this actually worked:

```
:/baa/,/quz/s/baa/bar/
```

Comment: this is an interesting solution, I was thinking of `\n`s in `:%s`